# Github Web API authorization issue - returns "Not found"

Tags: node.js, github, authorization, github-api

Since I don't find anyone with the same problem, I'm hoping it's a simple thing. And I'm fairly newb.

It's a Node/Express app and I'm trying to connect to Githubs Web API and retrieve issues for a certain repo. I have generated a personal token and I'm using it with Basic Authorization. When I try to connect I get: "*Not found*". Github state that where authentication is necessary they return 404/403, and I get 404, so it has to be something with the authentication. The repo has issues.

There shouldn't be a problem with the token, I choosed "repo" as access scope.

Actually I have no idea what I'm doing making HTTP requests but I've tried with both request and http. So among other things I'm wondering if it's something with the Authorization header that's wrong.

I paste the code I have right now using request, and the body returned. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
const githubToken = process.env.TOKEN;

    let options = {
        url: "https://api.github.com/repos/myOrg/myRepo/issues/",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + githubToken,
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    let requestCB = function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            let info = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(info);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(body);
        }
    };

    request(options, requestCB);
```

And the end of the response and the body:

```
 read: [Function],
 body: '{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}' }
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

---

EDIT:

So I found help with this, posting solution below. I guess the problem was that the accept-header have to be included. Perhaps the hostname, path and uri have to be in this format aswell.

```
let options = {
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "GitHub-username",
            "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
            "Authorization": "token " + githubToken
        },
        hostname: "api.github.com",
        path: "/repos/org/repo/issues",
        uri: "https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/issues",
        method: "GET"
    };
```

Comment: I think it could be because of the last `/`. If you have the last `/` you will need to provide the issue number for your request. Try removing it i.e. - `url: "https://api.github.com/repos/myOrg/myRepo/issues"`

Comment: Hey @Poonacha, I never saw this suggestion. Thanks. I have found a solution now though.

Answer (score 2):

Basic authentication require no token

### Basic Authentication

```
curl -u "username" https://api.github.com
```

So in your request, you can omit `githubToken`

See the [docs for more information about types of authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

### Using a token

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "token ",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}
```

request(options, callback);

Comment: Thanks. :)

The thing is I want/have to use Basic Authorization aswell as a personal token. It should be possible with the correct headers, right?

Also I've never used cURL so I have to use headers through request/http. At least this time. :)

Comment: @eiwob If you want to use token use this "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN"
if you don't and want to use basic basic authorization, you don't need the token. because they said so in the link mentioned above.
Yeah you don't need curl that was just a demonstration.

Comment: @eiwob, I think I should add this so it'll be a more complete answer.

Comment: Ooh... I've been trying this but replaced the "OAUTH-TOKEN" part, with the actual token. Have read that documentation several times but never got it, I really have become braindead at this point. :) But where do I place the actual token then?

Comment: @eiweb, ok, I understand now where you coming from ,please try 
`"Authorization": "Basic ", 
"access-token": githubToken`
and tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: @eiwob, if that doesn't work try the updated solution above (with or without the authorization header) until finding a working solution

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it didn't work. However now I get "bad credentials". I've tried alot of things, and now I'm glad to get it to work without token aswell... :) Right now I use this, which still gets me "Not found". Just trying to get basic authentication to work, but it's not.

    const base64 = require("base-64");
    const encodedCredentials = base64.encode("username:myPassword");

    "Authorization": "Basic " + encodedCredentials